# Project using DocViewer in React

Tags: reactjs

I've created a React project on replit. It's a simple example trying to use DocViewer. However, the viewer is never displayed. I've installed the package react-doc-viewer, and uploaded a couple of pdfs into the public directory in the app. Can someone tell me why nothing appears when I run the code? Thanks.

```
import DocViewer from "react-doc-viewer";

function App() {
  const docs = [
    { uri: require("../public/entertainer-let.pdf") },
    { uri: require("../public/maple-a4.pdf") },
  ];

 return <DocViewer documents={docs} />;
}

export default App;
```